# Rails on iPhone with JQTouch login issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, jqtouch

I have a rails app with a mobile view using jqtouch. If the application is viewed on an iPhone application.mobile.erb loads in place of the default application.HTML.erb.

Everything works fine, except the login. Users can login and then view the content. However, they have to login everytime they load the site. Is there a way of making the iPhone store the credentials as a cookie or similar?

I have noticed that if I view the desktop version on my iPhone and login, my login credentials are stored so I don't have to login everytime. Once I switch over to the iPhone specific jqtouch version I have to login every time.

The difference is that on the desktop version I enter the login details directly into the login form I made, but on the iPhone jqtouch version a popup from the iPhone UI requests the login information.

The application uses the Restful Authentication plugin: http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication

Thanks,

Danny

You can view the application on github:

```
www.github.com/dannyweb/baseapp2
```

Comment: This is probably more of an HTTP authentication question than jqtouch or rails.

Comment: To be honest, I have never fully understood http authentication etc. Would you suggest deleting the question and starting again?

Comment: Hi Danny, I have to admit — I'm not a RoR dev, but I did make jQTouch, and there is a good chance this is a more basic auth issue. I imagine the issue lies with the Restful Auth plugin (though probably not their fault). A quick question: Are you launching the app in fullscreen mode? Have you tried disabling this if so?

Comment: Hi David, when you say fullscreen do you mean when you add thee page to your homescreen and launch it from there? if so, I have tried both but had no luck. It's way beyond my knowledge of Rails, jquery and HTTP authentication which leaves me stumbled! Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I kind of mean that — moreover I mean does it launch with the browser chrome or not. (in jQTouch this is `fullscreen: true`). I think this affects cookies/sessions. Your best bet is to make your own auth system, and store some sort of hash (that you can validate server-side) in localStorage or SQLite. This will be more reliable for fullscreen apps.

Comment: Incidentally, you've included the Restful Authentication sitekey in your public git repository. Please don't deploy with the same key. See the `vendor/plugins/restful_authentication/README` file for details on safe handling of the sitekey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm fairly new to RoR, so this is my best guess and may be totally off...

I noticed that in your `app/views/dashboard` you have `index.html.erb` and `index.mobile.erb`, so I'm assuming that you're using a .mobile suffix for getting your iPhone specific mobile pages.. In your `lib/authenticated_system.rb`, your access denied method is:

```
  def access_denied
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          store_location
          redirect_to new_session_path
        end
        # format.any doesn't work in rails version < http://dev.rubyonrails.org/changeset/8987
        # you may want to change format.any to e.g. format.any(:js, :xml)
        format.any do
          request_http_basic_authentication 'Web Password'
        end
      end
    end
```

This method gets called whenever an unauthorized user tries to access content (see your `authorized` method to see what qualifies a user as authorized). This method responds to requests based on the format requested.. i.e. any `.html` requests hit the `format.html do` block. Since there's no `format.mobile` block, all .mobile requests end up hitting the `format.any` block. This results in the behavior you explained in your question:

> The difference is that on the desktop
>   version I enter the login details
>   directly into the login form I made,
>   but on the iPhone jqtouch version a
>   popup from the iPhone UI requests the
>   login information.

The other difference between the two is that `format.html` creates a session, while `format.any` only requests credentials and does not make a session.

Have you considered adding a `format.mobile` block to specify how the authentication system should handle .mobile requests so that a session is created (similar to the `format.html` block)?  You could even try using the same request_http_basic_authentication method (so that the iPhone UI request the credentials), but then do something with the submitted credentials to create a session or cookie.

Again, I may be totally off base, but hopefully my answer does more help than harm!